# ViewModel property for multiple selection in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a `one-to-many` set of values in a form. Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153210/mvc-5-multiselectlist-binding-values-with-model-selectlist-property) answer may be what I need, as per requirement I can't use a `@Html.ListBoxFor` since I need to provide detailed information of each item, so it would be better to use a `checkbox` input for selection.

The problem is I don't know how to bind these checkboxes to a property (if possible an `ICollection<MyType> myItemList`) in my viewmodel.

My `View Model` contains said property, so that the `GET Create()` view can use it and display info propery info for each item. So I'm having troubles on `POST Create(MyViewModel vm)` to get the list of selected values (or just the IDs)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you can alter your property in your model to be:

```
List<MyType> myItemList
```

and we can add a property to `MyType` to signify selection:

```
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

Then you can do:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.myItemList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.myItemList[i].Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.myItemList[i].Text)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.myItemList[i].IsSelected)
}
```

**NOTE:** I've assumed `Id` is the ID and you have a text field called `Text` in the code above.

Then to get selected items, your `HttpPost` method would be something like:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel Model)
{
    var selections = Model.myItemList
        .Where(m => m.IsSelected)
        .ToList();

   //do what you want with those selections
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind checkboxes to a list like this...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(IEnumerable<int> selectedValues)

<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedValues[]" value="2" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `value` attribute on the checkboxes would be your id values